# Connect Multiple VLANs which reside on same L3 Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, layer3

**Introduction**

[The steps described in this manual](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html) have been applied in order to enable the connection between multiple VLANs which reside on the same switch.

Two VLANs have been configured.

*VLAN 1:*

```
ip address 10.1.2.1 255.255.255.0
```

*VLAN 2:*

```
ip address 10.1.3.1 255.255.255.0
```

*Ports:*

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 2
!
```

*Network Adapter System 1:*

`10.30.50.71/24`

*Network Adapter System 2:*

`10.30.50.72/24`

Both systems are able to access each other if the ethernet cables are connected to ports which reside to `VLAN 1`.

If one of the ethernet cables has been moved to a port which belongs to `VLAN 2`, the systems are not able to access each other any more.

Will interVLAN solve this issue? What kind of commands are available to facilitate troubleshooting this issue?

**Question**

How to connect Multiple VLANs which reside on the same L3 Switch?

Comment: What port are you using as your L3 port? Can we get a dump of the configs for the switch? Specifically the port configs and confirmation that the "ip routing" command has been entered?

Comment: Did you configure default gateways on your systems?  They should match the address of the Vlan interface(s)

Comment: @HAL the ports running-config snippet has been added to the question

Comment: @HAL `sh run` confirms that `ip routing` command has been entered

Comment: @Ron while `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 200.1.1.2` has been executed, `sh ip route` indicates that `Gateway of last resort is not set`

Comment: @Ron `200.1.1.2` was configured as a default gateway on both systems, but the systems were not able to access each other probably due to `Gateway of last resort is not set` on switch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default gateway on your systems is incorrect.  The systems on VLAN 1 must have their default gateway set to 10.1.2.1, the address of the VLAN 1 interface.

Likewise, the systems on VLAN 2 should have their default gateway set to 10.1.3.1, the interface for VLAN 2

There is nothing you need to change on the switch.

Comment: The default gateways were changed as described in the answer. However, a system connected to VLAN1 was not able to ping a system connected to VLAN2, while systems connected to VLAN1 are able to access each other. This is applicable to systems connected to VLAN2 as well. The solution of specifying default gateway is not working at the moment probably due to incorrect static IPs. IP system1: `10.30.50.71`, IP system2: `10.30.50.72`.

Comment: Yes, your system IP addresses MUST be in the same subnet as your VLAN.

Comment: I will test this tomorrow and let you know the outcome

Comment: The IP addresses have been changed and reside in the same subnet as the VLAN. The systems can access each other now. Thank you.